# Posting to a user's wall in FB with permission, possible?

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-wall

is it possible to login to a website with a FB login and have the user post to his friend with permission? By "with permission" I mean the friend has to approve the post. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FB.api 'post' returns error](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/17267012/fb-api-post-returns-error)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. We have an application at my job that posts on the user's profile, as them, every week.

From the facebook doc (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/):

If you have an authenticated user with the publish_stream permission, and want to publish a story to their feed:

```
var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```